# DNP3 protocol - How is the data stored?

Tags: dnp3

I am new to DNP3 protocol and I have a question.

I understand that the data is stored in arrays
But, I did not understand if the array could be noncontinuous?

In addition, Is there any beginners source information for DNP3 protocol? (I have tried to read the DNP3 specification but it was unclear to me)

I would appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, data indexes may be non-contiguous.

To achieve "more efficient" transmission of data, section 5.1.2 of the [IEEE Standard for Electric Power Systems Communications— Distributed Network Protocol (DNP3)](https://standards.ieee.org/standard/1815-2012.html) states that "gaps in the point index range are permissible but should be avoided wherever possible."

The DNP3 standard does not specify how data is stored, but rather how it is transmitted.  The indexes are part of an addressing scheme used to identify individual pieces of data in a device.  A given piece of data, or point, is identified by its **Group** number and an **Index**.  For example, "Group 30 : Index 9" is the 10th readable, analog value ("10th" because the lists are zero-based).

Another way to state the answer is that point addresses (meaning indexes within a Group) are not required to be contiguous.

Note that even if points in a device are indexed contiguously, the device could return data with non-contiguous indexes in a single transmission packet.  For example, a packet of data from a device might contain the 2nd, 5th, and 12th readable, analog input.

I don't have any specific recommendation for beginners information.